# How do I add consumable In App Purchases using NSUserDefaults and not my own server?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, in-app-purchase

I'm new so I need simple answers if at all possible. I have my first app just about done (but it's not even submitted to the store), and I want to add In App Purchases. My app is a game where the user starts with some virtual currency "coins". I want to add an IAP for them to be able to buy more coins at three to maybe five different price points.

I have seen a ton of tutorials and it seems the info is mixed. Can anyone help me out on how to proceed here, in a way that's realistic for a very new developer and relevant to my particular case. I'd like to add IAP for free but if there is a simple paid solution that's really worth it, that might be okay.

I am using Xcode 4.3.2. I would like to use NSUserDefaults and not my own server and I have code in place for the NSUserDefaults. At least it stores the "coins" and has a key for the value.

Additionally are things different now that IOS 6 is out, do I need a whole new version of Xcode?

Thanks for your help, please forgive my inexperience in writing good questions :)

Comment: If you have code for `NSUserDefaults` in place, what are you unsure about? When the purchase completes successfully, simply save the coin value and then retrieve it when necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am just unsure of how to even get started on IAP. There are a lot of tutorials but none that addressed IAP for consumables and NSUser defaults etc... was looking for kind of first steps type thing...

Answer (score 4):

Since nobody answered this, I will..even if only to help people who view this later.

Please acknowledge, I have not used in-app purchases yet.. but I'm an experienced obj-c programmer & i believe i understand the concept after viewing the apple docs once... here is a very simple example for "consumable" in-app purchases (*Note, you should include more here if they are non-consumable or otherwise):

Firstly, include the "StoreKit" objective-c framework into your project.

I created this simple class called "InAppPurchaser" - Please include this class also..

"InAppPurchaser.h":

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

@protocol InAppPurchaserDelegate <NSObject>
- (void) InAppPurchaserHasCompletedTransactionSuccessfully:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction productID:(NSString *)productID;
- (void) InAppPurchaserHasCompletedTransactionUnsuccessfully:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction productID:(NSString *)productID error:(NSError *)error;
@end

@interface InAppPurchaser : NSObject <SKPaymentTransactionObserver>

@property (nonatomic, retain) id <InAppPurchaserDelegate> delegate;

#pragma mark Instantiation...
- (id) init;
+ (InAppPurchaser *) purchaser;
+ (InAppPurchaser *) purchaserWithDelegate:(id <InAppPurchaserDelegate>)delegate;

#pragma mark Utilities...
- (void) purchaseProductWithProductIdentifier:(NSString *)productID quantity:(NSInteger)quantity;
- (void) restoreTransactions;

@end
```

"InAppPurchaser.m":

```
#import "InAppPurchaser.h"

@implementation InAppPurchaser

@synthesize delegate;

- (id) init {

    if ( self = [super init] ) {

        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];

    } // ends condition...

    return( self );

} // ends method...

+ (InAppPurchaser *) purchaser {

    return( [[InAppPurchaser alloc] init] );

} // ends method...

+ (InAppPurchaser *) purchaserWithDelegate:(id <InAppPurchaserDelegate>)delegate {

    InAppPurchaser *purchaser = [InAppPurchaser purchaser];
    purchaser.delegate = delegate;

    return( purchaser );

} // ends method...

#pragma mark Actions...

- (void) purchaseProductWithProductIdentifier:(NSString *)productID quantity:(NSInteger)quantity {

    SKMutablePayment *payment = [[SKMutablePayment alloc] init];
    payment.productIdentifier = productID;
    payment.quantity = quantity;

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

} // ends method...

#pragma mark SKPaymentTransactionObserver...

- (void) paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {

    for ( SKPaymentTransaction * transaction in transactions ) {

        switch ( transaction.transactionState ) {

            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
                break;

            default:
                // ...
                break;

        } // ends switch statement...

    } // ends loop...

} // ends method...

- (void) completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {

    if ( delegate != nil && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(InAppPurchaserHasCompletedTransactionSuccessfully:productID:)] )
        [delegate InAppPurchaserHasCompletedTransactionSuccessfully:transaction productID:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];

        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

} // ends method...

- (void) restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {

    if ( delegate != nil && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(InAppPurchaserHasCompletedTransactionSuccessfully:productID:)] )
        [delegate InAppPurchaserHasCompletedTransactionSuccessfully:transaction productID:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];

        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

} // ends method...

- (void) failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {

    if ( delegate != nil && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(InAppPurchaserHasCompletedTransactionUnsuccessfully:productID:error:)] )
        [delegate InAppPurchaserHasCompletedTransactionUnsuccessfully:transaction productID:transaction.payment.productIdentifier error:transaction.error];

        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];

} // ends method...

- (void) restoreTransactions {

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];

} // ends method...


@end
```

Example usage:

"MyClassViewController.h":

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "InAppPurchaser.h"

@interface MyClassViewController : UIViewController <InAppPurchaserDelegate>

@end
```

"MyClassViewController.m":

```
#import "MyClassViewController.h"

@interface MyClassViewController ()

@end

@implementation MyClassViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

} // ends method...

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

} // ends method...

#pragma mark Purchasing...

- (void) myPurchaseMethod {

    InAppPurchaser *purchaser = [InAppPurchaser purchaserWithDelegate:self];
    [purchaser purchaseProductWithProductIdentifier:@"MyProduct" quantity:1];

} // ends method...

- (void) InAppPurchaserHasCompletedTransactionUnsuccessfully:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction productID:(NSString *)productID error:(NSError *)error {

    // handle success code.. IE: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"MyProduct"];

} // ends method...

- (void) InAppPurchaserHasCompletedTransactionSuccessfully:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction productID:(NSString *)productID {

    // handle failure code...

} // ends method...

@end
```

This code was not tested, but it should work.. Obviously, it can be improved, but it should get you started.

And lastly, you would want to use this in your AppDelegate as well.. call it as you would from the ViewController, except do not charge a purchase.. simply call the "restoreTransactions" method that I included.. This will restore any incomplete transactions that occurred due to app or internet connectivity failure or whatever.

Example:

In "AppDelegate.h":

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, InAppPurchaserDelegate>
```

in "AppDelegate.m":

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    InAppPurchaser *purchaser = [InAppPurchaser purchaserWithDelegate:self];
    [purchaser restoreTransactions];

    return( YES );

} // ends method...

- (void) InAppPurchaserHasCompletedTransactionUnsuccessfully:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction productID:(NSString *)productID error:(NSError *)error {

    // handle success code.. IE: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"MyProduct"];

} // ends method...

- (void) InAppPurchaserHasCompletedTransactionSuccessfully:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction productID:(NSString *)productID {

    // handle failure code...

} // ends method...
```